How can I control the first and second derivative using scipy CubicSpline?
Is there a way to connect two points using CubicSpline and set the 1st and 2nd derivatives to specific values?
I tried something like this:
boundary_conditions = (((1, dxdy1_spline), (2, 0.0)), ((1, dxdy2_spline), (2, 0.0)))  
spline = CubicSpline(x_spline_values, y_spline_values, bc_type = boundary_conditions) 

But I got this erros when I tried:
ValueError: The specified derivative order must be 1 or 2.

Per the documentation, bc_type must be a 2-tuple, so you can only specify the 1st or 2nd derivative at the start and the 1st or 2nd derivative at the end. You can't set both at both ends.

It's been a while since I've looked at the equations for generating a cubic spline, but I believe specifying more than a single BC at each end would overdefine the system.

I guess defining both derivatives might actually overdefine the system

You can try using make_interp_spline, which allows a bit more flexibility than CubicSpline. That said, asmentioned in the comments the linear system might overdetermined. Even if it is not, setting two boundary conditions at one side and leaving the other side completely free is definitely bound to have an accumulation of error, so do watch out for what happens at that other side of the interval.
EDIT: and if you want to enforce four boundary conditions in total, you can't do it with a cubic spline, you need a quintic one (make_interp_spline with k=5)
